# Python PyQt5 CreateTable class inheriting QtWidgets.QTableWidget to add add_row function

Tags: python, inheritance, pyqt5, qtablewidget

I am trying to create an application with a table in it to display rows of data. When more data arrives, I'd like to add a row and enter the data. However, I'm stuck at adding the row. Also, my own CreateTable class that inherits QtWidgets.QTableWidget works, but I don't understand why the line

```
self = QTableWidget(win)
```

is required. I've tried to keep the code as simple as possible just now until I get round having the table as an object with custom functions (add_row, delete_row...). Here is my code:

```
from PyQt5 import QtWidgets
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication, QMainWindow, QTableWidget, QTableWidgetItem
import sys

class CreateTable(QTableWidget):

    def __init__(self, win):
        super().__init__()
        # Doesn't display table without the next line. I don't understand why it is required.
        self = QTableWidget(win)
        # 
        self.setGeometry(50, 50, 1820, 920)
        self.setRowCount(10) 
        self.setColumnCount(10)

    def add_row(self):
        rowcount = self.rowCount()
        self.insertRow(rowcount)

class MainWindow(QMainWindow):

    def __init__(self):
        """MainWindow constructor."""
        super().__init__()
        # Main UI code
        self.setGeometry(0, 0, 1920, 1040)
        self.setWindowTitle("Order Manager")

        table = CreateTable(self)
        table.add_row()


# Main code
app = QApplication(sys.argv)
win = MainWindow()
win.show()
sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

This code opens the window and displays a table with 10 rows, but doesn't add the row to make 11 rows. I am quite new to OOP and PyQt5, but am trying to learn more!

New working code:

```
from PyQt5 import QtWidgets
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication, QMainWindow, QTableWidget, QTableWidgetItem
import sys

class MainWindow(QMainWindow):

    def __init__(self):
        """MainWindow constructor."""
        super().__init__()
        # Main UI code
        self.setGeometry(0, 0, 1920, 1040)
        self.setWindowTitle("Order Manager")

        self.table = CreateTable(self)
        self.table.add_row()


class CreateTable(QTableWidget):

    def __init__(self, win):
        super().__init__(win)
        self.setGeometry(50, 55, 1820, 920)
        self.setRowCount(10) 
        self.setColumnCount(10)

    def add_row(self):
        rowcount = self.rowCount()
        self.insertRow(rowcount)


# Main code
app = QApplication(sys.argv)
win = MainWindow()
win.show()
sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Comment: You need to call `super().__init__(win)` in `CreateTable.__init__`. This sets the parent of the `CreateTable` instance to `win`. Also, you should set the parent of the table widget to the central widget of `MainWindow` rather than to `MainWindow` itself.

Comment: Thank you! I'll include the new code above...